# How to make my variable synchronized with a LocalStorage variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, components, blazor, local-storage

I'm developing light/dark mode to my fullstack application(.Net/blazor) which has many component;
I'm trying to store the different values of my Tags in localstorage that change with the selected mode(light/dark); there are tags in Blazor  that don't take class as parameter that's why I'm using LocalStorage to set its values.

I have Mainlayout component which is my main component where you can find the switch mode button and also I have a component which contains the tag that i want to change its background color using localstorage :

MainLayout component :

```
private async Task ChangeThemeAsync()   //changeMode function linked to my button 
    {
        _themeName = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("CurrentTheme");
        if (_themeName == "DarkTheme")
        {

            //_currentTheme = _lightTheme;
            _themeName = "LightTheme";
            await localStorage.SetItemAsync("CurrentTheme", "LightTheme");
            await localStorage.SetItemAsync("DiagramColor", "#e9eaed");
            await localStorage.SetItemAsync("LabelColor", "#000000");
            var module = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/ThemeChanging.js");
            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("setTheme", _themeName);
            /*            await localStorage.SetItemAsync("CurrentTheme", _currentTheme);  */   //I added this line because i want to store a variable of type Mublazor in my localstorage
        }
        else
        {
            //_currentTheme = _darkTheme;
            _themeName = "DarkTheme";
            await localStorage.SetItemAsync("CurrentTheme", "DarkTheme");
            await localStorage.SetItemAsync("DiagramColor", "#1c1b20");
            await localStorage.SetItemAsync("LabelColor", "#FFFFFF");                      //we an clean the code that we can set the itm 
            var module = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/ThemeChanging.js");
            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("setTheme", _themeName);
            //await localStorage.SetItemAsync("CurrentTheme", _currentTheme);
        }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _themeName = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("CurrentTheme");

        if (_themeName.Equals("DarkTheme"))
        {
            var module = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/ThemeChanging.js");
            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("setTheme", _themeName);
        }
        else
        {
            var module = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/ThemeChanging.js");
            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("setTheme", _themeName);
        }
}
```

the component that contains the tag that i want to change its value :

```
    <SfChart Background="@DiagramColor" Height="600" Title="Teilemenge pro Prozess" > 
       </SfChart>
    
    @code{
        public string theme ="";
        public string DiagramColor= "";
        public string LabelColor="";
    
        public async Task load()
        {
    
    DiagramColor = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("DiagramColor");
    LabelColor = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("LabelColor");
        }
      protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            theme = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("CurrentTheme");
            DiagramColor = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("DiagramColor");
            LabelColor = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("LabelColor");
    
    }
    

}
```

All i need is to call the  Task load() in my Mainlayout while pressing on the button ;

I have tried to create an object of the component which contains the load() in Mainlayout component and call the load function throw the object but it shows an error : reference null ; in my case i can't add @ref to my child component because i'm using @body to call all the child component once, so i can't add reference to my @body to create an object,

Any suggestion please .?

Comment: This sounds better suited for a service. Have a service with an event `OnThemeChanged` and inject it into your components.

Comment: true , using a service that detect that changing theme event ( I'm using a button so the event is gonna be button clicked : 
 public class ComponentCommunication
    {
        public event Action OnButtonClicked;
#pragma warning disable
        public async Task ButtonClicked()
        {
             OnButtonClicked?.Invoke();
        }
    }

--> ty  for ur help